# How to add random white noise to data

Tags: python, numpy, random, noise, whitenoise

Suppose I have a column of data whose value ranges from -1.23 to +2.56. What I want is to add 10% random white noise to my data. I'm not sure how to do it in python; please help me with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add independent Gaussian (normal) randomness to your values.

Technically it need not be Gaussian.  White noise is called that because it has a flat spectrum, meaning it is composed of all frequencies in equal proportions.  The [Weiner-Khinchin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem) shows that this is mathematically equivalent to having the serial correlation be zero.  Many people believe that it requires Gaussian noise, but independence is sufficient to yield a flat spectrum.

Comment: Can you please provide me the code, I'm unable to make one